# Migrating Content Builder Assets from one SFMC instance to another

Tags: marketing-cloud

My company is migrating from an old instance of Marketing Cloud to a new one. Does anyone know if it's possible to migrate Content Builder assets like emails, templates, headers, images, etc. from one instance to another?

Comment: It is possible to do it yourself, but it is very time and effort intensive. It is usually recommended to use a SFMC partner to handle this. They have extensive experience in this as well as special tools created to do this efficiently. The cost of the partner will likely be less than the manpower and hours required to handle it internally.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, no, not without an API-based tool or an engagement with Salesforce or a partner.

Most API-based products can move quite a bit but are limited by the Marketing Cloud web services.

Answer (score 0):

There are vendors that have products that do this. One that comes to mind is https://levdigital.com/what-we-do/campaign-studio/

This is pretty much what you would have to do on your own via APIs, but turned into a product.

If you plan to do it on your own I would recommend looking at this amazing postman collection

https://api.mcexperts.ninja/

The 200+ calls it has, could get you started. But you would have to create an extract, and then a create from the source to the target instances.